# Webdav credentials OS X where

Tags: macos, webdav

I can automatically login to webdav server but have forgotten user/password.
Where on OS X High Sierra are these credentials stored so I can access and store them elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

These credentials are stored in your keychain, which you can see using Keychain Access, an application in the Utilities folder. Search for the IP address or hostname you use to connect to your WebDAV server.